Why does this comment change the functionality of this code?
In Excel I have a table of data that I'm pulling into a script. One of the columns contains values from a lookup table.
Simplified sample tables:
DataTable:



Value
Category
Exclude




123
A



456
A



789
B



12
C
X


34
D



56
D




LookupTable:



Category
Description




A
Something


B
Some other thing


D
Something else



I'm trying to verify that all non-excluded categories in the data table exist in the lookup table. This is what I ended up with:
dataTable.filter((e)=> e[exclude] == "" )                  // filter to non-excluded
.map((e) => e[category] )                                  // only look at the category column
.filter((e, ind, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) == ind )           // filter to unique categories
.every((e) => {
    if ( lookupTable.findIndex( (x) => x[category] == e) < 0 ) {
        console.log(e);                                    // Magic console log function
        messages.push ("Mapping not found for " + e);
        return false;
    }
} );

if (messages.length){
    showMessagesAndQuit();
}

I'm sure there are simpler ways to do this, but this was working for me; when I removed the value from the exclude column, it would spit out the "Mapping not found for C" message. But when I removed the console.log line, it would then fail later on in the script when it tried to access something using that lookup value. Logging the messages array before checking the length confirms it is empty without the log, but the message is there with it.
It also works if the log is outside of the if statement but still within the every function.
Any idea why this would be happening?

Hi @Ajschuit, could you share your entire script, or enough of a code snippet to allow us to reproduce the issue?
